# Infinite looping,c logical thinking

Tags: c, loops, logical-operators

I'm facing a problem with what I enter with any unknown during the first time to the program. it will show me an infinite loop problem program closing. The program won't read the `else` statement.

```
    char cont;

    printf("Do u want continue\n");
    scanf("%c", &cont);
    getchar();
    do
    {
        if (cont == 'y' || cont  == 'Y')
        {
            selection();
        }
        else if (cont  != 'n' || cont  != 'N')
        {
            printf("Program Closing \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid Please Re-enter");
            getchar();
            scanf("%c", &cont);
        }
    } while (cont  != 'n'&& cont  != 'N');
```

Comment: If I type `a` then is `next != 'n'` true or false? Is `next != 'N'` true or false? Is `next != 'n' || next != 'N'` true or false?

Comment: Why have a loop for that when you can just have it as an if else statement? Maybe use `goto` as well if you won't accept any other inputs aside from y/n

Comment: If you type 'Y' then `selection` is called, and `cont` keeps the value 'Y' forever. Also, if you put a space in the `scanf`, then you don't need the `getchar`. Should be `scanf(" %c", &cont)` in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's dissect your code line by line starting with

```
scanf("%c", &cont);
```

This line would get a char value from stdin and put it into cont, which is a char so that's fine

```
getchar();
```

All I have to say for this is, why? it doesn't do anything useful, remove it.

Entering the loop now we have this statement

```
if (cont == 'y' || cont  == 'Y')
```

this line is correct, it checks if the character is equal to `y` or `Y`

```
else if (cont  != 'n' || cont  != 'N')
```

this line is the main issue, your statement checks if cont is a value NOT equal to `n` or `N`, i.e. as a comment mentioned above, if the user put in the value `a` this line would return true, and then end the program. To correctly check if the user wants to exist you can use the same if statement used for `y`

```
if (cont == 'n' || cont  == 'N')
```

if you replace the original if statement with this your program should work as expected. Just remember in the future that the `!=` means not equal to, i.e. if the value is anything besides `n` or `N` return true. The `==` operator checks for equality as you saw above, so the line `cont == 'n'` means return true if cont is the same value as `'n'`

```
printf("Invalid Please Re-enter");
getchar();
scanf("%c", &cont);
```

also as an extra note, please explain why you keep throwing in useless `getchar()`'s, those lines literally do nothing and you should remove them.

Comment: Note that `getchar();` does something (it has side-effects).

Comment: maybe so, that's why I asked for an explanation, but whatever that reason is it's probably a bad idea to let behavior like that remain in your program, however that's a completely different issue.

Comment: What I meant is that one cannot automatically remove them (the "literally do nothing" implies it).

Comment: The `getchar()` is there to eat the newline character that `scanf` leaves behind.